# jquery - Better to use valid HTML in IDs or escape meta-characters?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, html

The application I am developing requires that the non-alphanumeric selector characters, hyphen (-), and underscore(_), be reserved for application use.  For a while I have delimited the characters with commas, but it causes trouble for me when I need to directly select the elements.

Here is an idea of how I have set things:

```
<td id="tableName,columnName,primaryKeyName,primaryKeyValue>
```

THE PROBLEM

I cannot use hypens because the GUID generator inserts hyphens every 8 characters, making them a troublesome deliminator.  I also have it mandated that applications using the template I have created must make their database table and column names lower case with an underline delimiter.

I see myself stuck with two options: fudge parsing by using hyphen delimiters and remembering where to reconcile the GUID format, or sticking with commas and using the jquery escape character (//) in my selection code.

Is there a best practice for this kind of thing?  Is there an option I do not see?

Thank you.

Comment: If you don't want to escape, you can use attribute selectors: `[id = "a,b"]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use data attributes?

```
<td id="some-td" data-id="tableName,columnName,primaryKeyName,primaryKeyValue">
```

---

```
$td = $('[data-id="..."]')
$sameTd = $('#some-td') // same TD as the above line
$sameTd.data('id') // tableName,columnName,primaryKeyName,primaryKeyValue
```

Bonus: You can put whatever you want in there

```
<td data-id="{'tableName':'myTable'}">
```

---

```
data = JSON.parse($sameTd.data('id') || 'null');
data.tableName; // myTable
```